# The relation between a polynomial's multiplicity and that of its derivative.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

Say a polynomial $p(x)$ has $n$ real roots with a multiplicity of $k$.

It can be shown that $p'(x)$ has a multiplicity of $k-1$.

$$ p(x) = (x-a)^k\cdot h(x) $$
$$ p'(x) = k\cdot (x-a)^{k-1}\cdot h(x) + (x-a)^k\cdot h'(x)$$
$$ p'(x) = (x-a)^{k-1}(k\cdot h(x) + (x-a)\cdot h'(x))$$

Is it true in reverse? If I show that the derivative of a function $f(x)$ has a multiplicity of $k-1$, does this mean that $f(x)$ having multiplicity of $k$ is true?

Comment: If you're talking about orders of zeroes as in the context of analytic functions, then yes.

Comment: It's not the multiplicity of a polynomial that you're talking about here, but rather the multiplicity of a _root_ of a polynomial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $f$ has a zero there at all, then yes. Otherwise no. Consider for example $f(x)=x^k+1$ at $x=0$: the derivative has a zero of order $k-1$ but the function itself has no zero at all.